# lift-json with scala 2.10

Tags: scala, sbt, lift-json

I am following the tutorial [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/getting-started-with-scala-and-scalatra_12.html) and stuck with json-lift dependency.

This is the dependency in my plugings.sbt file:

```
addSbtPlugin("net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.4")
```

The error is below and it seems to be something related to scala 10.2 not being compatible but anyone know of a way I can get lift-json working with scala 10.2 ?

```
haknick '~/Projects/NickProjects/sometryouts/myscalatrys/scalatra/live-aq-first' --> scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.10.2 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
haknick '~/Projects/NickProjects/sometryouts/myscalatrys/scalatra/live-aq-first' --> scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.10.2 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
haknick '~/Projects/NickProjects/sometryouts/myscalatrys/scalatra/live-aq-first' --> sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/kreshnikmati/Projects/NickProjects/sometryouts/myscalatrys/scalatra/live-aq-first/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/kreshnikmati/Projects/NickProjects/sometryouts/myscalatrys/scalatra/live-aq-first/project/}default-7238ba...
[info] Resolving net.liftweb#lift-json;2.5 ...
[warn]  module not found: net.liftweb#lift-json;2.5
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.liftweb/lift-json/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/net.liftweb/lift-json/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/kreshnikmati/.ivy2/local/net.liftweb/lift-json/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/liftweb/lift-json_2.9.2_0.12/2.5/lift-json-2.5.pom
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_10_1;0.12.3 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: net.liftweb#lift-json;2.5: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      net.liftweb:lift-json:2.5 (sbtVersion=0.12, scalaVersion=2.9.2)
[warn] 
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: net.liftweb#lift-json;2.5: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:214)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:117)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:117)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:105)
    at sbt.IvySbt.liftedTree1$1(Ivy.scala:52)
    at sbt.IvySbt.action$1(Ivy.scala:52)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:61)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:61)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:102)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:98)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:117)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:955)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:953)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$58.apply(Defaults.scala:976)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$58.apply(Defaults.scala:974)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:978)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:973)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:981)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$47.apply(Defaults.scala:858)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$47.apply(Defaults.scala:855)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf10$1.apply(Structure.scala:586)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf10$1.apply(Structure.scala:586)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: net.liftweb#lift-json;2.5: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

lift-json is not a plugin, but dependency

you should be able to use it by defining:

```
libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.5.1"
```

in your build.sbt file

Comment: Thank you very much sir.
The original article had it inside plugins.sbt.

Answer (score 22):

If you are using scala 2.11, add the following to your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.6+"
```

Answer (score 2):

Sbt file using Scala 2.11.8:

```
name := "Basic Lift-JSON Demo"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" % "lift-webkit_2.11" % "3.1.0"
```